# Convergence in Hausdorff metric

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, convex-analysis

Consider a sequence $(A_n)$ of bounded, convex subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\text{int}(A_n)\neq\emptyset$ for all $n$ and  $\text{clo}(A_n)\neq \text{clo}(A_m)$ whenever $m\neq n$, where $\text{int}(\cdot)$ and $\text{clo}(\cdot)$ denotes interior and closure, respectively.

Suppose $A_n\rightarrow A$ in the Hausdorff metric.

Is it true that every sequence $(x_n)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $x_n\in A_n$ for all $n$ converges to a point in $A$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No not quite. The sequence may jump around within $A_n$. E.g. A_n a line interval that rotates to a fixed interval $A$. And $x_n$ jumps up and down the interval as n increases. You'd have to pass to a subsequence of $x_n$ to get convergence.

Comment: Thank you. Is the argument for the existence of a convergent subsequence obvious or does it follow from some known result (e.g. some generalization of Theorem 1.8.7 in Schneider's 1993 "Convex bodies" book)?

Comment: If the sets $A_n$ are bounded then everything takes place in a bounded region and so the sequence $\{x_n\}$ is bounded and so there will always be a convergent subsequence $x_{n_k} \to x$. But actually, if $A$ is already given to you, then it might in principle be an open set and then it needn't be the case that $x \in A$, only that $x \in \mathrm{clo}(A)$.